# unable to put a <table> tag inside a div tag

Tags: php, html, css, xhtml

I am trying to put a  inside a  tag like in the example below, but the table is displayed outside the tableWrapper div, the tableWrapper div is displayed correctly I want but the table is outside it and I don't understand what am I doing wrong, can any one help? :

```
//the buttons 
$html .= '<p><form method="post" action = "DBTest.php" >
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
    </form></p>';   


//start table
$html.= '<div id = "tableWrapper"><table>';

foreach($rows as $row)
    {

         $id= $row['id'];
         $title = $row['title'];
         $year = $row['YEAR'];
        //put everything on a table
        $html.= "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['title'] . "</td><td>"  . $row['year'] . "</td><td>";
     }
$html.= '</table></div>';    

//the main body
$alpha['main'] = <<<EOD

{$html}

EOD;
```

Here is my tablWrapper div:

```
#tableWrapper{
    clear:both;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
}
```

Here is my table css:

```
table {margin-bottom:1.4em;}
th {font-weight:bold;background:black;color:white;}
th,td,caption {padding:4px 10px 4px 5px;}


tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {background:#A1912A11;}
tbody tr:hover td {background:#9E9E80;}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: ending </tr> is missing in you foreach loop

Comment: Why assign, `$id`, `$title`, `$year` but not use them?

Comment: 1) When the problem is with client-side rendering, show the client-side code.  2) Any time you have HTML rendering problems, the *first* thing you should do is validate the markup: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typos:

```
    $html.= "<tr><td>" [...snip...] . "</td><td>";
                                            ^^^^
```

You never close your `<tr>` tags, and end the line with a new unterminated `<td>`. So you end up with

```
<div><table>
<tr><td>...</td><td>..</td><td>
<tr><td>...</td><td>..</td><td>
etc...
```